# Custom query in SXA search scope

Tags: sxa, content-search, sitecore-commerce

Using Sitecore, I have defined some tags, related to food or pet type and assigned some of these tags to pages

[image]

How can I limit search scope to find all pages which have any food tag assigned ?

Comment: I've done something similar with SXA (but no Commerce) with a custom token: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/01/extending-sxa-search-query-tokens.html Can elaborate on it in an answer if this might be useful for you?